# Is this statement about the solution to an elliptic problem true.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be an open bounded convex domain.  Let $f\in L_2(\Omega)$.  We actually know that $f$ doesn't have higher regularity.  Let the pair $(\Psi,\vec{\Phi})\in L_2\times H(\mathrm{div})$ be the solution to the following elliptic PDE in mixed form.

\begin{align*}
0&= \vec{\Phi}+\vec{\nabla} \Psi& \mathrm{for\ } x\in \Omega\\
f&= \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{\Phi}& \mathrm{for\ } x\in \Omega\\
0&= \Psi& \mathrm{for\ } x\in \partial\Omega_D\\
0&= \vec{\Phi}\cdot \vec{\eta}& \mathrm{for\ } x\in \partial\Omega_N
\end{align*}

We assume that the measure Dirichlet boundary $\partial\Omega_D$, in nonzero.

Does there exist a constant $C$, dependent only on the domain, such that

$$\left\| \vec{\Phi} \right\|_{L^2} + \sum_{i=1}^d \left\|\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x_i}\Phi_i  \right\|_{L^2}  \le C \left\| f \right\|_{L^2}?$$

## My attempt

We use elliptic regularity as follows:

\begin{align*}
&\left\| \vec{\Phi} \right\|_{L^2} + \sum_{i=1}^d \left\|\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x_i}\Phi_i  \right\|_{L^2}\\
&\le \left\| \vec{\Phi} \right\|_{L^2} + \left| \vec{\Phi} \right|_{H^1}\\
&= \left\| \vec{\Phi} \right\|_{L^2} + \left| \Psi \right|_{H^2}\\
&= \left| \Psi \right|_{H^1} + \left| \Psi \right|_{H^2} \\
&\le \left\| \Psi \right\|_{H^2}\\
&\le C \left\|f\right\|_{L^2}
\end{align*}

We use elliptic regularity in the last inequality.  Note that here is where we use the fact that the domain is convex.  Is there a problem with this estimate?  All references I have seen for elliptic regularity results assume that there is no Neumann boundary.  I appreciate any references to the literature where elliptic regularity is proven for this case.

Comment: You probably can do it for a (non-convex) $C^2$ domain.

Comment: Have you looked at Brezzi & Fortin (1991)?

Comment: @OskarLimka, No I haven't but I think my library has it.  I will look in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the Dirichlet boundary is of positive measure your proof looks correct. Note that the Neumann boundary condition is necessary for the well-posed part. Once you know your solution exists and is unique, you may replace Neumann with a Dirichlet condition.

Comment: I guess I don't follow what you mean in this sentence, "Note that the Neumann boundary condition is necessary for the well-posed part."  The boundary has Dirichlet BC's on part of it and Neumann BC's on another part of it.  My understanding is that as long as there is some part of the boundary with Dirichlet BC's then the problem is well posed.  Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Yes. What I meant is that once you know there is a unique solution in some subspace of $H^1(\Omega)$ and you are interested in the regularity of this solution, you do not need to worry about the Neumann condition.  (Whereas the Dirichlet condition might still be useful, for example, to apply Poincaré type arguments.)